# Cartesian product and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we prove that
$(A\cup C)\times (B \cup D) \subset (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \Rightarrow (C \subset A ~\land ~ D \subset B) ~~ \lor ~~ (A \subset C ~ \land ~ B \subset D) $?

I've tried to prove by contradiction but didn't manage to do it.
I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we apply the distributivity of $\times$ over $\cup$ we obtain the following conditions from the antecedent:

$$C \times B \cup A \times D \subseteq A\times B \cup C \times D$$

Now $C\times B \not\subseteq A \times B \cup C \times D$ iff both $C \setminus A$ and $B \setminus D$ are non-empty.

Similarly, $A \times D \not\subseteq A \times B \cup C \times D$ iff both $A \setminus C$ and $D \setminus B$ are non-empty.

Therefore, we conclude that:

$$C \times B \cup A \times D \subseteq A\times B \cup C \times D$$

is equivalent to:

$$\neg(C\setminus A \ne\varnothing \land B\setminus D \ne \varnothing) \land \neg(A \setminus C \ne\varnothing \land D\setminus B \ne\varnothing)$$

which, using the De Morgan's laws for negation, translates to:

$$(C\setminus A =\varnothing \lor B\setminus D = \varnothing) \land (A \setminus C = \varnothing \lor D\setminus B =\varnothing)$$

Using the equivalence of $X \setminus Y = \varnothing$ and $X \subseteq Y$, we obtain:

$$(C\subseteq A \lor B\subseteq D) \land (A \subseteq C \lor D\subseteq B)$$

and by using distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$, we obtain the disjunction:

$$C =A \lor (C\subseteq A \land D\subseteq B) \lor (A \subseteq C \land B\subseteq D) \lor B = D$$

In conclusion, if we take $\subset$ to mean $\subsetneq$, two of these possibilities drop out, and we obtain the result. But if we take $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$, it is false (as exhibited by Brian M. Scott).

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually false as stated: if $A$ and $C$ are disjoint non-empty sets, and $B=D$, then

$$(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)=(A\cup C)\times B=(A\times B)\cup(C\times B)=(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\;,$$

but $C\nsubseteq A$ and $A\nsubseteq C$.

It’s true if you further assume that $A\ne C$ and $B\ne D$. Then you can argue as follows. Since $A\ne C$, assume first that $C\nsubseteq A$. Let $c\in C\setminus A$, and let $x\in B\cup D$ be arbitrary. Then $\langle c,x\rangle\in(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$, so $\langle c,x\rangle\in(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)$, and clearly $\langle c,x\rangle\notin A\times B$, so $\langle c,x\rangle\in C\times D$ and therefore $x\in D$. Thus, $B\cup D\subseteq D$, and it follows that $B\subseteq D$. If we also have $A\nsubseteq C$, we can show similarly that $D\subseteq B$ and get the contradiction that $B=D$, so it must be that $A\subseteq C$. That is, if $C\nsubseteq A$, then $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$. If we assume instead that $A\nsubseteq C$, we can argue similarly to show that $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$.